# what are the functionality for Salesforce Connected Apps?

Tags: salesforce1-app

what are the functionality for Salesforce Connected Apps ??

We are migrating from classic to lightning . We need to check if those functionality of this APP Salesforce (Connected Apps) is working in lightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connected Apps don't have much to do with Classic versus Lightning. They define the authentication rubric under which off-platform applications connect to Salesforce. While the UI for managing Connected Apps changes in Lightning Setup relative to Classic Setup, the apps themselves do not change. They are distinct from Salesforce Apps or Lightning Apps.